# changing POSIXct date vaules to first day of each week

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I want to calculate the average `Dist` for each week using these data (below) while preserving the benefits of a using the `POSIXct` time class.

```
    df <- structure(list(IndID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "AAA"), 
    Date = structure(c(1329436800, 1329458400, 1329480000, 1329501600, 
    1329523200, 1329544800, 1329566400, 1329588000, 1329609600, 
    1329631200, 1329652800, 1329674400, 1329696000, 1329717600, 
    1329739200, 1329760800, 1329782400, 1329804000, 1329825600, 
    1329847200, 1329868800, 1329890400, 1329912000, 1329933600, 
    1329955200, 1329976800, 1329998400, 1330020000, 1330041600, 
    1330063200, 1330084800, 1330106400, 1330128000, 1330149600, 
    1330171200, 1330192800, 1330214400, 1330236000, 1330257600, 
    1330279200, 1330300800, 1330322400, 1330344000, 1330365600, 
    1330387200, 1330408800, 1330430400, 1330452000, 1330473600, 
    1330495200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Dist = c(3.85567120344727, 52.2649622620809, 1043.61207930222, 
    1352.58506343616, 176.911523081261, 77.8266318470078, 50.3943567710686, 
    296.753649985307, 70.5826583995618, 166.394264991861, 251.745346701973, 
    295.70655057823, 44.6664731663839, 11.1539274078084, 124.578071475754, 
    757.728373470112, 83.0921234152083, 36.6820839851181, 29.1406161870034, 
    150.442928003814, 66.0957159105813, 2.23839297570488, 184.88312900824, 
    513.072526047611, 132.868335201626, 8.09274857805967, 284.479977841835, 
    479.358187122796, 297.273840894826, 4.00676616275076, 601.492189218489, 
    249.001525522847, 108.007775719885, 2.38435966274261, 604.365702677913, 
    1499.59076416313, 111.74722960012, 25.3528529967124, 280.057754683142, 
    428.157539641219, 70.0365608334965, 71.0886617898624, 265.823654634254, 
    380.247565078552, 188.857338305481, 9.24402933768915, 120.346786301264, 
    221.904294953242, 201.086079767386, 81.7857577639103), DoW = c(5, 
    5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("IndID", "Date", 
"Dist", "DoW"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")

> head(df)
  IndID                Date        Dist DoW
1   AAA 2012-02-16 17:00:00    3.855671   5
2   AAA 2012-02-16 23:00:00   52.264962   5
3   AAA 2012-02-17 05:00:00 1043.612079   6
4   AAA 2012-02-17 11:00:00 1352.585063   6
5   AAA 2012-02-17 17:00:00  176.911523   6
6   AAA 2012-02-17 23:00:00   77.826632   6
```

My thought was to use the `plyr`package to average `Dist` by week and wanted to first create a new `WeekDate` field that contains the date, excluding the time, of the first day of each week.  As seen in the DoW (Day of Week) field, data does not always begin on the first day of the week.

While i cannot seem to connect the dots, I want the min Date excluding h:m:s) for each sequential week (DoW 1-7).

Rows 1:10 would be 2012-02-16,
    Rows 11:38 would be 2012-02-19,
    Rows 39:50 would be 2012-02-26

I suspect the `lubridate` package will be helpful but can not get the code correct.

Any suggestions or alternative methods on the specific creation of a new date column or more broadly averaging Dist for every week would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using bosom buddy of `plyr`,

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Week = floor_date(Date, unit="week")) %>% 
  summarize(WeeklyAveDist=mean(Dist))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#        Week WeeklyAveDist
#1 2012-02-12      381.7755
#2 2012-02-19      252.1116
#3 2012-02-26      175.4097
```

There are also `ceiling_date`, `round_date` options.

Comment: slick.  A twofer! much appreciated.

Comment: I'd vote this up twice if I could. +1 for lubridate.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `strftime` with `%W` format:

```
> strftime(as.Date("2015-01-08"), "%W")
[1] "01"
```

You could use this to define a new variable and then aggregate by this variable. Maybe thus

```
> df <- transform(df, week=strftime(Date, "%W"))
> aggregate(df$Dist, by=list(df$week), FUN=mean)
  Group.1        x
1      07 319.8861
2      08 254.2861
3      09 161.0421
```